# Using socketio-file-upload to upload multiple files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, npm, socket.io

Im using NodeJS with socket.io and [socketio-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-file-upload) to upload multiple files, it works great! However I'm having an issue where I'm trying to save the name attribute of the input these files come to save them into my DB.

When I upload 1 or more files, I can't seem to access the input field name or something that shows me which of the files come from which input field.

Here is my front:

```
var uploader = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);

var array_files_lvl_3 = [
    document.getElementById("l3_id_front"),
    document.getElementById("l3_id_back"),
    document.getElementById("l3_address_proof_1"),
    document.getElementById("l3_address_proof_2"),
    document.getElementById("l3_passport")
];

uploader.listenOnArraySubmit(document.getElementById("save_level_3"), array_files_lvl_3);
```

And here is my back:

```
var uploader = new siofu();
uploader.dir = "uploads/userL3";
uploader.listen(socket);

uploader.on('saved', function(evnt){
    console.log(evnt);
    //this "event" variable has a lot of information 
    //but none of it tells me the input name where it came from.
});
```

This is what the "evnt" variable holds:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the library doesn't send that information. So there is nothing existing config you can do. So this needs code modification.

**client.js:374**

```
var _fileSelectCallback = function (event) {
    var files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
    event.preventDefault();
    var source = event.target;
    _baseFileSelectCallback(files, source);
```

**client.js:343**

```
var _baseFileSelectCallback = function (files, source) {
    if (files.length === 0) return;

    // Ensure existence of meta property on each file
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (source) {
            if (!files[i].meta) files[i].meta = {
                sourceElementId: source.id || "",
                sourceElementName: source.name || ""
            };
        } else {
            if (!files[i].meta) files[i].meta = {};
        }
    }
```

After these changes I am able to get the details in `event.file.meta`

[image: element]

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of socketio-file-upload.

It looks like the specific input field is not currently being recorded, but this would not be a hard feature to add.  Someone opened [a new issue](https://github.com/sffc/socketio-file-upload/issues/88) and left a backpointer to this SO question.

A workaround would be to directly use `submitFiles` instead of `listenOnArraySubmit`.  Something like this might work (untested):

```
// add a manual listener on your submit button
document.getElementById("save_level_3").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let index = 0;
  for (let element of array_files_lvl_3) {
    let files = element.files;
    for (let file of files) {
      file.meta = { index };
    }
    uploader.submitFiles(files);
    index++;
  }
});
```